# How to convert buffer to file to download on react side

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-html-to-pdf to convert html to pdf in nodejs. I have a react frontend and nodejs backend. I want to convert the buffer to a file that people can download on the react side. How can I do this? I don't want to save the file on my servers.

Answer (score 0):

We can set header [`Content-disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) `attachment` to indicate that the response is a downloadable file.

Backend: example in Express

```
const htmlToPDF = new HTMLToPDF(`
  <div>Hello world</div>
`);

const buffer = await htmlToPDF.convert();

res.set("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="test.pdf"`);
res.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

res.send(buffer);
```

Frontend: example in React

```
const submit = () => {
  window.open("http://localhost:8000"); // Your endpoint here
};

return (
  <button onClick={submit}>Download</button>
);
```

If the endpoint is POST method then `window.open` won't work. We have to use a form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000" method="POST">
  <button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```